# Is it an efficient and a good practice to pass huge pandas dataframes as function parameters and also return them from functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I apologize for asking a dumb question but kindly advise me regarding this.

**Scenario a: I need to write 1.5GB pandas dataframes as csv files into SharePoint location.**

Approach 1:

```
# function to write dataframe to sharepoint location
def writeData(largeDataframe,uname,pwd,relpath,filename):
    baseCtx=getSharePointContext(uname,pwd) # another function to authenticate and get sharepoint context
    target_folder = baseCtx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(f"Shared Documents/{relpath}")
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    dfResult.to_csv(buffer, index=False,encoding='utf-8',lineterminator='\n')
    buffer.seek(0)
    file_content = buffer.read()
    target_folder.upload_file(fileName, file_content).execute_query()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lisFiles=["aa.csv","bb.csv"....] # list having 100 csv files
    for file in lisFiles:
        df=pd.read_csv(file) # have 
        # do something with df
        writeData(df,uname,pwd,relpath,filename)
```

Approach 2:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lisFiles=["aa.csv","bb.csv"....] # list having 100 csv files
    for file in lisFiles:
        df=pd.read_csv(file)
        baseCtx=getSharePointContext(uname,pwd) # another function to authenticate and get sharepoint context
        target_folder = baseCtx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(f"Shared Documents/{relpath}")
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        dfResult.to_csv(buffer, index=False,encoding='utf-8',lineterminator='\n')
        buffer.seek(0)
        file_content = buffer.read()
        target_folder.upload_file(fileName, file_content).execute_query()
```

Is there any difference in efficiency or performance? which one is the recommended approach for best performance and greatest speed?

**Scenario b: I need to read nearly 1.5GB csv files stored in SharePoint into pandas dataframes.**

Approach 1:

```
# function to read dataframe from sharepoint location
def readData(url,uname,pwd):
    largeResult=None
    baseCtx=getSharePointContext(uname,pwd) # another function to authenticate and get sharepoint context
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0)

    largeResult=pd.read_csv(bytes_file_obj,dtype=str,encoding='utf-8')
    return largeResult


if __name__ == '__main__':
df1=readData(url1,uname,pwd);
```

Approach 2:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    baseCtx=getSharePointContext(uname,pwd) # another function to authenticate and get sharepoint context
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, url1)
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0)

    df1=pd.read_csv(bytes_file_obj,dtype=str,encoding='utf-8')
```

Is there any difference in efficiency or performance? which one is the recommended approach for best performance and greatest speed?

Comment: is `dfResult` intended to be `largeDataframe` and or `df`?

Comment: In both scenarios, the network latency will affect your performance more than anything you can gain CPU-wise with either approach. Even a wired 10Gbit Ethernet network will cause significant IO delay

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you pass a DataFrame or other object in and out of a function as long as you don't explicitly make a copy of it-

Python uses names ([1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) [2](https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)), so the backing memory will be roughly the same regardless of how many references there are to a particular object, and Pandas is largely backed by NumPy arrays and works with views of them

So if you have pass a DataFrame to a function, modify it, and then return it, the *name* passed in and whatever you *name* the output will both refer to the same object, which is managing a collection of further references

---

If you have multiple scenarios and test code for them, just try it and see which is faster - with a lengthy list, try a few of the entries!

Finally, you may find Dask or Polars can be used to farm out and lazily deal with the data, avoiding loading all of the data at once entirely, though this is a departure from your current design

- https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html#persist-intelligently
- [What are the advantages of a polars LazyFrame over a Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76612163/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-polars-lazyframe-over-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

## Both methods should be fine

There shouldn't be any (meaningful) overhead when passing huge objects to/from functions. This is because Python will never copy anything unless you tell it to. So when you pass things to/from functions, you're not actually passing the data, only a reference to the data. Here is an example to let you get a feel for it:

```
import sys

class MyHugeObject:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Creating object', file=sys.stderr)
        self.huge_list = ['data' for _ in range(100000000)]

    def __del__(self):
        print('Destroying object', file=sys.stderr)

def mutate(obj):
    obj2 = mutate2(obj)
    obj2.huge_list[5] = 'newdata'
    return obj2

def mutate2(obj):
    obj.huge_list[8] = 'newerdata'
    return obj

huge = MyHugeObject()
mutated_huge = mutate(huge)

print(mutated_huge.huge_list[5])
print(mutated_huge.huge_list[8])

del huge
```

Output:

```
Creating object
newdata
newerdata
Destroying object
```

When you run this, you will see that it does take a long time to create the huge object, but any operations on it are quick. Moreover, you will notice that the object gets created and destroyed only once. There are no copies being created.

Actually, since we now know that Python objects (and pretty much all variables) are passed by reference, we don't actually need to `return` anything from the functions in the example above.
Since `obj2`, `obj`, and `huge` will point to the same object, you can simplify the code like this:

```
def mutate(obj):
    mutate2(obj)
    obj.huge_list[5] = 'newdata'

def mutate2(obj):
    obj.huge_list[8] = 'newerdata'

huge = MyHugeObject()
mutate(huge)

print(huge.huge_list[5])
print(huge.huge_list[8])

del huge
```

### Errata

I used the `__del__` magic method in my demonstration. Please don't use it in your code, unless you know what you are doing. It is [not a very intuitive magic method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFjuQmlwXgU&pp=ygUPbWNvZGluZyBfX2RlbF9f).